# Delphi: Adding JSON Array to JSON Object

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-2010

I am calling a 3rd Party API using Indy

```
var loRespJson: TMemoryStream;
IdHTTP1.GET(lsURL, loRespJson)
```

and it returns a JSON array:

```js
[
    {
        "Active": "1",
        "SourceId": "215",
        "SourceName": "MyVal1"
    },
    {
        "Active": "1",
        "SourceId": "383",
        "SourceName": "MyVal2"
    }
]
```

In turn my function creates a new JSON object, adds additional info plus the response, and return it to the calling program. Desired result:

```js
{
    "responseCode":"200",
    "companyNo":"0268895",
    "responseMessage": [
        {
            "Active": "1",
            "SourceId": "215",
            "SourceName": "MyVal1"
        },
        {
            "Active": "1",
            "SourceId": "383",
            "SourceName": "MyVal2"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I achieve the above? If I add using the following, it creates "" (quotes) around the array which is a big problem when parsing the JSON:

```
loJSon.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('responseCode', IntToStr(idHttp1.ResponseCode)));
loJSon.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('companyNo', CompanyNo));

if idHttp1.ResponseCode = 200 then
begin
  lsRespMsg := StreamToString(loRespJSon);
  liSuper := SO(lsRespMsg);
  loJSon.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('responseMessage', liSuper.AsJSon()));
  …
```

I have also tried looping through the JSON aray but that option adds "" around each array item

```
{ create an json-array }
loJSA := TJsonArray.Create();
{ add array to object }
loJSP := TJSONPair.Create('responseMessage', loJSA);
loJSon.AddPair(loJSP);

if liSuper.IsType(stArray) then
begin
  for i := 0 to liSuper.AsArray.Length - 1 do
  begin
    loSubscription := liSuper.AsArray[i];
    loJSA.Add(loSubscription.AsJSon());
  end;
end;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You are mixing 2 different libraries to process JSON - [SuperObject](https://github.com/hgourvest/superobject) and [System.JSON](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON). Pick one as a good start.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you used `loJSon: TJSONObject` from unit [System.JSON](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON) in your attempt to build JSON new response. Then you parsed response body received from `TIdHTTP` using function `SO()` from [SuperObject](https://github.com/hgourvest/superobject) library, which is not very compatible with System.JSON.

The approach was good so far, but you should stick to a single library. After parsing the response you added a pair the TJSONObject with value `liSuper.AsJSon()` which was a string. And that explains the double quotes enclosing the array.

The proper solution using just System.JSON could look like this:

```
uses
  System.SysUtils, System.JSON;

const
  ResponseMessageStr = '[{"Active":"1","SourceId":"215","SourceName":"MyVal1"},{"Active":"1","SourceId":"383","SourceName":"MyVal2"}]';
var
  ResponseJSON: TJSONObject;
begin
  ResponseJSON := TJSONObject.Create;
  try
    ResponseJSON.AddPair('responseCode', '200');
    ResponseJSON.AddPair('companyNo', '0268895');
    ResponseJSON.AddPair('responseMessage', TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(ResponseMessageStr));
    Writeln(ResponseJSON.Format());
  finally
    ResponseJSON.Free;
  end;
end.
```

In the above snippet I used [`TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue) to parse response message and append it to the resulting JSON object. Although my response message is stored in a string constant, you can easily adapt the solution to be used with `TMemoryStream` or `TIdHTTP`. Check out all invariants of `TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue`.

The snippet produces output:

```js
{
    "responseCode": "200",
    "companyNo": "0268895",
    "responseMessage": [
        {
            "Active": "1",
            "SourceId": "215",
            "SourceName": "MyVal1"
        },
        {
            "Active": "1",
            "SourceId": "383",
            "SourceName": "MyVal2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also note that `TJSONObject.AddPair` has multiple invariants for your convenience. Another point is that I used `Format` method to pretty-print the content of JSON object, but you should probably use `ToJSON` in production.

Solution using SuperObject library that produces equivalent result:

```
uses
  System.SysUtils, SuperObject;

const
  ResponseMessageStr = '[{"Active":"1","SourceId":"215","SourceName":"MyVal1"},{"Active":"1","SourceId":"383","SourceName":"MyVal2"}]';
var
  ResponseJSON: ISuperObject;
begin
  ResponseJSON := TSuperObject.Create;
  ResponseJSON.I['responseCode'] := 200;
  ResponseJSON.S['responseCode'] := '0268895';
  ResponseJSON.O['responseMessage'] := SO(ResponseMessageStr);
  Writeln(ResponseJSON.AsJSon(True));
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction. My project is in Delphi 2010 so I couldn't use the example. However, standardizing to iSuperObject helped a lot and the fix was as simple as loResult.O['responseMessage'] := SO(lsRespMsg);

Comment: @Johan I have added snippet to perform the same task using SuperObject. Next time remember to put all the constraints in your question. We can't see where `TJSONPair` or `TJSONArray` come from.